# How do i recreate this Equirectangular option for the image texture

Tags: texturing, shaders

[image: Image Texture Node]

How do i recreate this.  because every time i make a new image texture node and try to change that option,  the Equirectangular option does not come up.  btw i am also in the object setting, not world setting

Comment: That option only exists for the *Environment Texture* node, not the regular *Image Texture* node.

Comment: oh thanks a lot dude!